# VBA get previous active control from parent form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, subform

I am usgin Access 2010 and I have a form that has a sub form, let's call it `sform`. I want to print the parent form's active control When I hit a button in `sform`. I tried

```
debug.print Me.parent.ActiveControl
```

But it prints the name of the sub form's container control, while I wanted the one that was active before it. Is that even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The active control on the parent form would be the sub form.  To figure out what control had the focus before the sub form you may have to do something like the following:

Add a text box to the form called `txtFieldThatHadLastFocus` or whatever and hide it.

Then in the ***On Lost Focus*** event of all your controls on the parent form add:

```
Private Sub txtMyField_LostFocus()
   txtFieldThatHadLastFocus.Value = "txtMyField"
End Sub
```

Then within the sub form you can figure out what control had focus before the sub form via:

```
Forms!ParentFromName!txtFieldThatHadLastFocus.value
```